# Mysql:Complex Update Query

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have states in user table state columns.Now using query i want to update city names in user city filed.I wrote this query but not working.

```
1. USER TABLE

state      city     user_id

AF                     1
BF                     2 
CF                     3

2. STATE TABLE

UF      Name     

AF      AAA      
BF      BBB      
CF      CCC      

2. CITIES TABLE

UF_STATES      Name     

AF             XXX      
BF             YYY      
BF             XZZ
```

**Query:**

```
UPDATE `user` SET `city` = 
(
    select name from cities WHERE uf = (select state from user)
)
```

Comment: What city would user 2 get?  There are two in the `cities` table.

Comment: What that query is saying is, return all state names and try to put it every user's city field.

Comment: What you are attempting is doomed to failure because a state can have more than one city.  Look at putting a cityID into your user table and a stateID into your cities table.

Comment: There should be a relation between `state` and `cities` table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume STATE is a consequence of CITY, so you might want to normalize your tables. As for your question you need to determine which city you should use for a given state. One example would be:

`UPDATE user 
    SET city = (
        select MIN(name) 
        from cities 
        WHERE uf = (select state from user)
    )`

Comment: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Mark, you are right. I keep forgetting about this limitation in mysql. Since the op did not post sample data as insert statements I did not try it.